# How do I change header location of curl content scraper

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, screen-scraping, http-head

I am scraping content from a url that is hosted in the UK using curl. When i view the site in my browser from the US it shows the product pricing in dollars but when i use curl to retrieve content it returns in Euros. I need it to return in US dollars as if you were viewing it from a browser in the US. Below is the code I am using

```
    function LoadCURLPage($url, $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-us; rv:1.4)
 Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)", 
$cookie = '', $referer = '', $post_fields = '', $return_transfer = 1, 
$follow_location = 1, $ssl = '', $curlopt_header = 1)
{

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


if($ssl)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
}

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $curlopt_header);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.16) Gecko/20080702 Firefox/2.0.0.16', 'Accept-language: en-us,en;q=0.7,bn;q=0.3', 'Accept-charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'));

if($agent)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
}

if($post_fields)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

if($referer)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
}

if($cookie)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
}

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

return $result;
}


 // the url
 $url = "http://us.asos.com/Adidas-Honey-Silver-Mid-Sneakers/ysrqb/?iid=2212284";

//the function 
echo LoadCURLPage($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in a cookie. So either visit the page that sets that cookie, or edit your cookiejar file.